# Which is better, minified or obfuscated code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

I’m confused between the two. Which is better, especially for jQuery and JS? Also, which do you think is more SEO-friendly? Note: *I’m a noob.*

Comment: I don't think that it matters.

Comment: minified code because obfuscated code is smaller but you should do more operations every time and the code will be cached when it is loaded the first time so the first loading time is not so important

Comment: +1 for confessing that you are noob. Me too but I never admited it but I'll do now :D

Comment: @chown Just edited the title. I'm really asking for opinions about using "minified" or "obfuscated" code. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

None of them. It will not be indexed (only in obscure odd cases).

Minifying JS is about loading speed and obfuscating JS is for making it harder for other developers to read your code.

Google does however rank your website based on load speed, and if you are including 15 JavaScript files and 20 stylesheets, your site gets slow and therefore loses rank. Therefore it's a great idea to combine these 15 JavaScript files into one and minify it, to minimize the loading speed.

This is because most user-agents (e.g. browsers) can only make 2 simultaneous requests on the same domain.

Comment: Hey Jan, thanks for explaining it **in layman's terms**!

Comment: Minify = pull out all the spaces and carriage returns so it loads fast, Obfusticate = muck it up to hide crappy code. Obfustication is easily overcome, what I've noticed is that it's a good indicator that you don't really want to copy the hack jobs it contains anyway. Find the effect in the obfustication, educate yourself on how it's really supposed to work and write it to proper W3C standards and you'll have better results.

Comment: Fiasco Labs, some times yes, but you missed the main point of the answer. My main point was actually about reducing http requests (which increases overall page speed) - and one great way to do this is combining/minifying css/js.

Answer (score 2):

If you minify your JavaScript, your page loads faster and that matters for SEO.